# Rails Stripe Connect Token Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

It seems that either a token is not being created properly or it's never being passed to stripe and I have no idea why. I've already removed turbolinks bc I've seen problems with that on SO. I've followed every guide I can. I've hooked up stripe payments before no problem and I can't solve this one after days of trying. Please help!

It's a simple payment form for my customers, so it just needs to be a one time charge. Not even setting up customers as of now.

The error I'm getting: You must supply either a source or a customer id

Error response from stripe:

```
error:
    type: "invalid_request_error"
    message: "You must supply either a source or a customer id"
```

new.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  // This identifies your website in the createToken call below
  Stripe.setPublishableKey('<%= @user.publishable_key %>');
  // ...
</script>


<%= javascript_include_tag 'payment' %>

<%= form_for @payment, html: {id: "payment-form"} do |f| %>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
  <%= f.text_field :amount, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Amount", class: "form-control" %>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" data-stripe="number" maxlength="20" placeholder="Credit Card Number" type="text"></input>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
  <input class="form-control" data-stripe="cvc" size="10" placeholder="Security Number" type="text"></input>
</div>
<div class="input-group">
    <center><p>Expiration Date:</p></center>
    <ul class="dates">
        <li><%= select_month(Date.today, {add_month_numbers: true},  class: 'form-control', data: {stripe: "exp-month"}, style: "height: 46px;") %></li>
        <li><%= select_year(Date.today.year, {start_year: Date.today.year, end_year: Date.today.year + 4}, class: 'form-control', data: {stripe: "exp-year"}, style: "height: 46px;") %></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <%= f.submit "Submit Payment", class: "btn btn-success col-xs-12" %>
</div>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Payments Controller:

```
def new
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    @user = @company.users.first
    @payment = Payment.new
end

def create
    @result = StripeWrapper::Charge.create(source: params[:stripeToken])
    if @result.present?
      @payment = Payment.create(payment_params)
      flash[:success] = "Thank you for your payment"
      redirect_to thank_you_path
    else
      flash[:danger] = @result.error_message
      render :new
    end
end

private

def payment_params
  params.require(:payment).permit(:user_id, :company_id, :reference_id)
end
```

Stripe_wrapper.rb

```
module StripeWrapper
class Charge
    attr_reader :error_message, :response

    def initialize(options={})
        @response = options[:response]
        @error_message = options[:error_message]
    end

    def self.create(options={})
        begin
            response = Stripe::Charge.create({
                amount: 1000,
                currency: 'usd',
                source:  options[:source],
                description: "test charge",
                application_fee: 123
            }, {stripe_account: 'client_account_id'}
            )
            new(response: response)
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
            new(error_message: e.message)
        end
    end

    def successful?
        response.present?
    end
end

class Customer
    attr_reader :response, :error_message

    def initialize(options={})
        @response = options[:response]
        @error_message = options[:error_message]
    end

    def self.create(options={})
        begin
        response = Stripe::Customer.create({
            card: options[:card],
            email: options[:user_email],
            description: "Service Pay"
            },
            {stripe_account: 'connect_client_id'}
        )
        new(response: response)
        rescue Stripe::CardError => e
          new(error_message: e.message)
        end
    end

    def successful?
        response.present?
    end

    def customer_token
        response.id
    end
end
end
```

payment.js

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#payment-form').submit(function(event) {
    var $form = $(this);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
    Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
    return false;
  });
});

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {
    $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
    $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
  } else {
    var token = response.id;
    $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
    $form.get(0).submit();
  }
};
```

Comment: What is `{stripe_account: 'client_account_id'}`, shouldn't it be `:customer => 'xxxxxxxxxxx'` in your list of options instead?

Comment: @Liyali that's for stripe connect. I'm taking payments on behalf of my customers. That's where their uid would go.

https://stripe.com/docs/connect/payments-fees

Comment: Also, isn't the `source` missing in the Customer class stripe API request?

Comment: I added the full log that Stripe gives...honestly it's not much but it's all that's showing up in their logs for this.

'source' and 'card' are inter-changable right now. I believe 'card' is going to be deprecated soon. but for this question it shouldn't matter because I'm not hitting that. But thank you for pointing that out I will correct that.

Comment: Yes I saw it wasn't called but just wanted to flag that. Have you tried to inspect the options hash sent to `Stripe::Charge.create` before the `begin` block? Can you also give us your code for the method `payment_params`? Thanks.

Comment: I added payment params. How do I inspect the hash?

Comment: Add `:stripeToken` into the `permit` method of `payment_params`, does that fix the issue?

Comment: now I'm receiving this error...which makes 0 sense: Received both source and customer parameters. Please pass in only one. (my code hasn't changed from what's above)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hopping on the stripe freenode channel and getting some help we figured out the problem and I wanted to leave the result here for anyone else having this problem.

It turns out that it was a javascript error from the morris.js charts library that was causing the rest of the javscript (namely the payment.js file) from not being executed and therefore not token was created.

The morris.js error was caused because the jquery was called to display a graph (from the asset pipeline), but there was no div container for the graph. I solved this by simply putting a div with the correct id, but no data element so no data is displayed and a style display:none so nothing is shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include Stripe.js? Add this at the top of new.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  Stripe.setPublishableKey("#{ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY']}");
</script>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'payment' %>
```

ENV['STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY'] should be set in application.yml or similar location. You also need to put this in the create controller before you call StripeWrapper

```
Stripe.api_key = ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
```

Comment: I did have that in there with the connected accounts publishable key...which did work when I inspected element it was showing the correct publishable key. I edited my question to reflect this. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: for the stripe secret I have that in an initializer and it's not giving me any indication that it's causing a problem. I have everything working except for the charge part. Connecting the accounts through oauth works, even creating customers works, but I can't charge and I can't figure out why.

Comment: I still don't see where you set your Stripe.api_key

Comment: set the Stripe.api_key before the call to StripeWrapper and see that it should work

Comment: Just tried that and it's still giving the same error.

Comment: Can you add a `binding.pry` in the controller before the call to StripeWrapper and check to see if `Stripe.api_key` and `params[:stripeToken]` give the correct values?

Comment: I added binding.pry but I didn't see anything about Stripe.api_key or params[:stripeToken] when I stepped through. Not sure what that means.

Comment: if they were both nil, that means your form isn't submitting correctly and you didn't set the Stripe.api_key. What do you see if you just type `params`